# my mails are not getting sent by php funtion mail()

Tags: php, email, xampp

I am trying to send emails from my gmail account using php (xampp).
I search over stackoverflow and as I got the things I changed my xampp's files sendmail.ini and php.ini as,

In C:\xampp\php\php.ini I removed the semicolon from the beginning of the line `extension=php_openssl.dll` to make SSL working for gmail for localhost.

in php.ini file under [mail function] I changed

```
SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
sendmail_from = mukul.agrawal19@gmail.com
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

Then in C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.ini. I replaced all the existing code in sendmail.ini with following code

```
[sendmail]

smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=mukul.agrawal19@gmail.com
auth_password=my-gmail-password
force_sender=mukul.agrawal19@gmail.com
```

then I wrote a simple mail function

```
<?php
$to = 'mukulagrawal13@live.com';
$subject = 'Test email'; 
$message = "Hello World!\n\nThis is my first mail."; 
$headers = "From: webmaster@example.com\r\nReply-To: webmaster@example.com";
$mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
echo $mail_sent ? "Mail sent" : "Mail failed";
?>
```

then went on the this page by my browser,
got echo as Mail Failed.

I saw my debug file and I got

```
14/12/03 18:24:00 ** --- MESSAGE BEGIN ---
14/12/03 18:24:00 ** To: mukulagrawal13@live.com
14/12/03 18:24:00 ** Subject: Test email
14/12/03 18:24:00 ** From:mukul.agrawal19@gmail.com
14/12/03 18:24:00 ** Reply-To:mukul.agrawal19@gmail.com
14/12/03 18:24:00 ** 
14/12/03 18:24:00 ** Hello World!
14/12/03 18:24:00 ** 
14/12/03 18:24:00 ** This is my first mail.
14/12/03 18:24:00 ** --- MESSAGE END ---
14/12/03 18:24:01 ** Connecting to smtp.gmail.com:25
14/12/03 18:24:08 ** Connected.
14/12/03 18:24:08 << 220 mx.google.com ESMTP o17sm23150442pdn.33 - gsmtp<EOL>
14/12/03 18:24:08 >> EHLO Mukul-PC<EOL>
14/12/03 18:24:10 << 250-mx.google.com at your service, [223.186.182.29]<EOL>250-SIZE 35882577<EOL>250-8BITMIME<EOL>250-STARTTLS<EOL>250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES<EOL>250-PIPELINING<EOL>250-CHUNKING<EOL>250 SMTPUTF8<EOL>
14/12/03 18:24:10 ** Authenticating as mukul.agrawal19@gmail.com
14/12/03 18:24:10 >> STARTTLS<EOL>
14/12/03 18:24:12 << 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS<EOL>
14/12/03 18:24:14 >> QUIT<EOL>

lots of codes in unknown language.

14/12/03 18:21:47 ** Disconnected.
14/12/03 18:21:47 ** Disconnecting from smtp.gmail.com:25
14/12/03 18:21:47 ** Disconnected.
14/12/03 18:21:47 ** Disconnected.
14/12/03 18:21:47 ** Connection Closed Gracefully.
```

Comment: Make `mail` command printing warnings (remove `@` in front) and take a loof at your `error_log`.

Comment: how to check error-log?

Comment: Find where Apache writes error log on your system and cat/vi it.

Answer (score 0):

use your real email address to get email.

$to = 'myeamilid@gmail.com'; replace this with your genuine email address

Comment: ya I am using my genuine one.. I changed it just to write here.

Comment: did you try changing smtp_port to 25 ??

Comment: yes..that too not workng

Comment: oh, if you got the solutions, let me know !!

Comment: Nope..Actually I forgot to restart the server. I restarted it and now my configuration has actually started working. But my mail is getting failed.

Comment: i got the solution buddy.. change your smtp domain name to your ISP.